# How can i convert my euro in BTC the fastest way

Tags: buy-bitcoins

consider me a crypto *noob*.

All i want is to transfer some **~10** euro (reside in my *prepaid mastercard*) to a BTC address (i have one, in my **blockchain** account).
Then i need to give those BTC to some service that have asked for that (like *0.001*); they also provided me a *QR-code*.

```
What is the fastest (like, right now) way you can think of to pay my service?
```

**PS.** I just got verified on blockchain (and became a *Gold* member), however when i try to deposit EUR/USD (in *Exchange*), it just shows me some bank information (recipient, where to send etc.), no paypal or anything else. I guess this way will take some time for money transfer.

Thanx for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to register in a Crypto Exchange and use this 10 Euro to buy Bitcoins, this value will be credited to your wallet.

I might suggest an exchange in your own country which will allow Euro deposits.

Answer (score 1):

I use Kraken.com from the UK bank transfers take 15 mins tops

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://bitbay.net
Here you can deposit in EURO and Buy Bitcoin and other cryptocurrency.